# Facing issues while sendkeys for a autosuggestion dropdown in a webapplication

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

1) On the current screen we have dropdown with div tag (Select Agent)

2) When we click on the dropdown, the options appear only till time the cursor stays on the dropdown, once moved the options vanishes.

3) We have tried sendkeys - to send text, JavaScript Executor - to send text, Action class - to click and hold, and send text,  - to get the options list while we have cursor on dropdown. no luck.

4) Most of the time the error "Element not interactable" or the execution halts and eventually exits.

I'm looking for something which can help me out here to enter text while the cursor focus is on the dropdown.

**Note:** If we click anywhere the dropdown list vanishes and we are not able get the entire list as its not the typical dropdown with Select and options.

Kindly suggest any solutions or workarounds when you have similar problems while automating a web application. Sorry can't copy the DOM contents.

[image: snapshot of DOM]

Comment: why u want to sendkey?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the HTML as code, not a screenshot. Screenshots are hard to read, and you cannot copy and paste the code into an answer.

Comment: Please also add the Java code you attempted to use to your question text.

Comment: @PDHide - to pass text, for selection from auto-suggested options, it's one of the RaectJS dropdowns..

Comment: @Greg Burghardt - 1. I completely understand it's difficult with snapshots,but we are prohibited to copy from DOM, it's banking site. 2. Sure give me some time will add the Java code soon.

Comment: Also for the time being I've worked it using Robot class but not able to pass text..

Comment: Can you post a representative snippet of HTML than?

Comment: try explicit wait for the dropdown

Comment: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/ is this website dropdown is similar to yours ?